# Python: list directory using user input as directory name not working

Tags: python, filesystems

I've been trying to solve this problem all day. I just want to list the files within a directory that a user will specify. Below is my code and traceback:

```
>>> os.listdir(r'{}'.format(input('directory:')))

directory:C:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
WindowsError: [Error 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax i
s incorrect: 'C:\r\\*.*'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give `C:` in string format.

Its working fine for me

```
>>> os.listdir(r'{0}'.format(input('directory:')))
directory:"C:\Users"
['All Users', 'Default', 'Default User', 'desktop.ini', 'Public', 'RanRag']
>>>
```

or try using [`raw_input`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#raw_input).

```
>>> os.listdir(r'{0}'.format(raw_input('directory:')))
directory:C:\Users
['All Users', 'Default', 'Default User', 'desktop.ini', 'Public', 'RanRag']
```

> The raw_input function reads a line from input, converts it to a string
>   (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that

If you are using `python3` than `raw_input` is replaced by `input`.

```
>>> os.listdir(r'{0}'.format(input('directory:')))
directory:C:\Users
['All Users', 'Default', 'Default User', 'desktop.ini', 'Public', 'RanRag']
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Apparently the problem was a bug within python 2.3 which I solved by using the following: `code`os.listdir('{}'.format(input('name:').rstrip('\r')))

Comment: I was just looking into it and was just going to say that there is an extra character `'C:\r\\*.*'`  `\r` in your stacktrace.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that the error lies in the use of [`input`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#input) instead of [`raw_input`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#raw_input).

If you use `input` python tries to parse the text the user entered. In your case you just want to have the string the user enters, so you either have to add quotes to the string (like RanRag did in his answer), or you could simply use `raw_input` as it returns the characters the user typed as a string.

Comment: And RanRag just updated his answer while I still was writing mine stating the exact same thing :D

Answer (score 0):

As RanRag said. But since you'll already get a string from raw_input you can do it like this:

```
os.listdir(raw_input('directory: '))
```